# Alt-based shortcuts in VS Code's intergrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

My shell is configured to have <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> navigate in history (technically, using zsh's `history-beginning-search-forward` and `history-beginning-search-backward`).

I used to be able to use these shortcuts in VS Code's integrated terminal, but since I upgraded to VS Code 1.74.1, the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> seem to be catched by VS Code before reaching my shell (the cursor changes to a cross to allow rectangular selection when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, which I guess is the cause). I do have `"terminal.integrated.sendKeybindingsToShell": true` and `"terminal.integrated.allowMnemonics": false` in my settings to avoid interference between VS Code and the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, and I couldn't find another setting to change the behavior. Surprisingly, the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> command is passed to the shell, so *some* <kbd>Alt</kbd>-based shortcuts are passed to the shell, but not all.

Is it possible to configure VS Code to send <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to my shell?

As a workaround, using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> seem to work, but that's one extra key to teach my fingers to use :-(.